# Using VIM with Anaconda Python install on Ubuntu GNOME3

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim, anaconda, gnome

I'm attempting to use VIM to edit and run python code. I would like to use the Anaconda install (Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)) when executing Python code.

Checking the version of Python from vim...

```
:!which python
/usr/bin/python  

:!which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Checking the version of Python from the terminal...

```
$ which python
/home/richard/anaconda3/bin/python

$ which python3
/home/richard/anaconda3/bin/python3

$ python -V
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
```

I installed VIM using instructions from youcompleteme, although I haven't yet installed any plugins. I configured vim for Python3 support.
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

```
$ ./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
            --enable-perlinterp=yes \
            --enable-luainterp=yes \
            --enable-gui=gnome2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr \
            --with-compiledby=Richard
```

The .bashrc file has the following lines...

```
# added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/home/richard/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

My goal is to execute the anaconda install of Python from VIM and use pandas, numpy, etc. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run code from VIM, it is not using the Anaconda install. I'd like help to understand how to redirect to use the Anaconda python '/home/richard/anaconda3/bin/python3'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  When I looked at what version of python my vim was compiled to use it was 3.5.The latest Anaconda is installing python 3.6 and so my vim did not know how to look for that. Try :version in vim and see what you get.  I get "/nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python35.lib"

When I uninstalled Anaconda, installed python 3.5, updated all my modules for 3.5 (e.g. numpy, etc.) vim found it as python3 and used it correctly.  I can't speak for all your vim add-ins.

One can use an older version of Anaconda (4.2.0) that installs python 3.5 and the Anaconda install page has other options/instructions for using python 3.5. Or look around for a compiled version of vim that uses python 3.6.